# Using ASP.net Identity user with other tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

I am just trying the new ASP.Net Identity, but run into some issues.

The first issue is that I found out that the ApplicationContext inherits IdentityDbContext rather than DbContext which I think has reasons.

The second issue is that since I will be using a lot of tables apart from the standard table generated by the Identity, should all my DbSet be declared within the ApplicationContext that inherits IdentityDbContext?

Comment: UserStore etc have a constructor that takes a vanilla DbContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your first issue is asking.  But for your second, no, you aren't required to use the context for managing other tables in your database.  I use the ADO.NET Entity Data Model for my application's tables typically, and only need to use the Identity Context for any Account/Role related controllers.

Comment: yes but what if you need to join then in your LINQ query's. How would you do that? bearing in mind the tables will be in different contexts.